# Regex.Matches returns full result in 0 position

Tags: c#, regex, .net-4.0

The following:

```
Regex.Matches("Some Text @param Some More", "(.*)(@param)(.*)")
```

returns

- Some Text @param Some More
- Some Text
- @param
- Some More

Is there any way to not have the first line? I cannot find any documentation on this. And, if I use online parsers, they only list the 3 groups...I would like to avoid having to code in the ignore first...

Comment: why does it bother you ?it\s how it works

Comment: Just `Skip(1)` after your matches. This is the normal behaviour of pretty much all Regex tools.

Comment: Because when I ask for my match groups, I expect the groups ()

Comment: @SimonBelanger I would be ok with that if I could. GroupCollection is not letting me run the enumerable extensions....I know the documentation says it is IEnumerable, but the IDE yells...

Comment: @JustinPihony Do `Regex.Matches.OfType<Match>` to access the enumerable extensions

Comment: @SimonBelanger Post that as an answer and I will accept. OfType is what I was missing

Comment: @sza No, I know the problem and wanted a pretty solution :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a named group captures to not have to work with indexing. Change to this:

```
Regex.Matches("Some Text @param Some More", "(?<One>.*)(@param)(?<Two>.*)")
```

then access the match data such as

```
var data1 = mt.Groups["One"].Value;
var data2 = mt.Groups["Two"].Value;
```

Comment: Choosing as the answer as this is the best to answer my question directly. I ended up going with the skip option once I used OfType, though

Comment: @JustinPihony index 0 is always the full match regardless of submatches. Then in order of match each index thereafter is each of the submatches. That is true on every match. By using named match captures one doesn't have to figure out which sub match is which.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
Regex.Matches("Some Text @param Some More", "^.*(?=@param)|@param|(?<=@param).*");
```

Comment: Nope, this does not work

Comment: @JustinPihony: retry now.